# Mysql: Unknown column in 'field list' on newly table

Tags: mysql

I just created a mysql table

```
CREATE TABLE `accounts` (
  `​user_id​` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `password` char(40) NOT NULL,
  `banned` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `active​` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created_on` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `last_logged` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`​user_id​`),
  KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

The following queries work 100% as expected:

```
Select name from accounts;
Select * from accounts;
```

However, the following queries result in the error (or similar)
**Unknown column 'user_id' in 'field list'**

```
Select user_id from accounts;
Select `user_id` from accounts
Select accounts.user_id from accounts
Select active from accounts;
```

I just deleted ALL the tables and recreated them and I am still getting this problem.

Comment: When I do Select * or Describe I see the columns listed

Comment: how do you try to "talk" to the db? By using a script? there might be encoding issues with your underscore? Is it working in PHPMyAdmin query window?

Comment: @evayly The underscore problem wouldn't explain why it also fails with `active`.

Comment: @user508771 Please edit your question to include the whole list of commands and their result of your SQL query when you delete them all, recreate them and how you try to access them. When you do this with the "mysql" command copy the whole program output to your question. When you run the query differently show it in your question as well.

Comment: I am using a mysql client to run these queries. @Progman There is a large project with a ton of queries and its hard to get the responses to them. So I deleted ALL tables from the mysql client, and ran the above queries in the mysql client and still get the problem. I am thinking its probably some db setting as the fields i added are the only ones I can specify in my select queries. Inserts work fine and select * works fine.

Comment: @user508771 Please edit your question to include the sequence of SQL commands which produce the error. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query